# Telephone mask (number format) with variable lenght

Tags: google-sheets, number-formatting

I was looking for the best solution to mask cells with telephone numbers like the example: 
(+55 11) 99999-9999
Normally I'd use `(+## ##) #####-####` as a custom number format. The problem is that the length of the number may vary. Nine numbers for cellphones and eight for home numbers. So, with a mask like that, an eight number phone would be formated like (+5 51) 19999-9999

Answer (score 1):

Well, while posting this question I found the solution I wanted using Custom Number Format with conditions based on the number value.

`[<=999999999999](+00 00) 0000-0000; [>999999999999](+00 00) 00000-0000;`